# Add Leaflet markers from two different AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet

I have two different JSON responses that are fetched from 2 AJAX calls. The first one plots data properly to a Leaflet Map. However, the second one doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
      var map = L.map('map').setView([22.6059596, 88.4277967], 13);

      L.tileLayer('http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/abhishekdepro.li9a02j1/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYWJoaXNoZWtkZXBybyIsImEiOiI3ZXg1UzlFIn0.d584w0ILalmPRzbJwgxdTw#4', {
          attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
          maxZoom: 18
      }).addTo(map);
      if (localStorage.getItem("user_contact") === null) {

      } else {
          document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "Hello, " + localStorage.getItem("user_contact");
          document.getElementById("_login").innerHTML = "Logout";
      }
      //var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
      //marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.").openPopup();

      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          url: 'https://bloodplus.herokuapp.com/geopoints',
          success: function (data) {
              var obj = data;
              var totalLocations = obj.length;

              var array = [];
              var greenIcon = L.icon({
                  iconUrl: '/images/icon.png',

              });
              array = obj.bloods;
              //alert(array.length);

              for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                  marker = new L.marker([parseFloat(array[i].tweet.lat), parseFloat(array[i].tweet.lon)], {
                      icon: greenIcon
                  })
                      .bindPopup(array[i].tweet.group + ', Contact: ' + array[i].tweet.contact).addTo(map);



              }
              another();
          }
      });

  });

  function another() {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          url: 'https://bloodplus.herokuapp.com/geopoints',
          success: function (data) {
              var obj = data;
              var totalLocations = obj.length;
              //document.getElementById('name').value = parseFloat(obj.bloods[0].tweet.lat);

              var array = [];
              var greenIcon = L.icon({
                  iconUrl: '/images/icon.png',

              });
              array = obj.bloods;
              //alert(array.length);

              for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                  marker = new L.marker([parseFloat(array[i].tweet.lat), parseFloat(array[i].tweet.lon)], {
                      icon: greenIcon
                  })
                      .bindPopup(array[i].tweet.group + ', Contact: ' + array[i].tweet.contact).addTo(map);



              }
          }
      });


  }
</script>
```

But when I make another AJAX request after this. The markers do not load and I get an error as:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 't.addLayer(this)')

Comment: It seems there isn't enough information provided to work with. TypeError is a common error when trying to access something from something that is **undefined**. The code you show up on top, is that the second ajax? What line is giving you the typeerror?

Comment: I have updated the entire code.

Comment: The `another` function is outside the function where `map` is defined. Move `another` inside the top function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use either `new L.Marker` or `L.marker`, not the combination of both - `new L.marker` . See Class Factories section in http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#class.

Comment: I have replaced it. Now, the error is in this line:

Comment: `marker = L.marker([parseFloat(array[i].lat),parseFloat(array[i].lon)],{icon: greenIcon})
        .bindPopup(array[i].group+', Contact: '+array[i].contact).addTo(map);` @snkashis

Comment: You have a trailing comma after `iconUrl: '/images/icon.png'` that needs to get removed, and also some other syntax errors - check your amount of `}` at the end of your functions.

Comment: Fixed everything. Same error. Here's the fixed code: `$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'json',
     url: 'https://bloodplus.herokuapp.com/userpoints',
     success:function(data){
        var obj = data;
        var totalLocations = obj.length;
         
        
        var array = [];
        
        array = obj.users;
       

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        marker = L.marker([parseFloat(array[i].lat),parseFloat(array[i].lon)])
        .bindPopup(array[i].group+', Contact: '+array[i].contact).addTo(map);
        
        
        
      }
    }
   });`

Comment: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 't.addLayer')

Comment: can you please init the marker the marker with `var marker = L.marker...`, and `console.log` it out...before you bindPopup to it.. It sounds like your markers are not being created properly.

Comment: Checked it. Its perfect. It has Object which on expanding gives the correct lat, lon co-ordinates as well as popups. In fact, this is what I did initially :)

Comment: You can also, suggest me an architectural change. Maybe I can send 2 AJAX requests and bind them to map in some other way?

Comment: Can you throw this entire setup into a Jsfiddle so we can see the entire flow?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xxfdwk32/ Its a little messed up. Everything is in html only. Hit the 'I want to Donate' button. It will run only donate() AJAX request and not the need()

Comment: You have JS and resource errors all over the place here.You need to include resources with JSFiddle's resources panel on the left before we attempt to debug this further.